# gnome-terminal ignores gtk theme

Tags: themes, gtk, gnome-terminal

I run oneiric with fluxbox as the window manager, and gnome-terminal appears to disregard gtk theme. The theme support *does work* in other gtk applications (for example, in gthumb and in firefox), but changing the theme makes no difference for gnome-terminal. I have oneiric, and I use lxappearance to change the theme. Am I wrong in assuming that gnome-terminal is a gtk application? Or is the problem elsewhere?

- Note that the checkbox "Use colours from system theme" in gnome-terminal configuration does not solve the problem, nor it is supposed to, since I am interested in the look and size of the menu, and the tabs, not their colour. ]
- LXAppearance version is 0.5.1, and so it appears that it is GTK3 compatible. It even creates the file gtk-3.0/settings.ini in the home directory which contains the selected settings. This, *I think*, rules out http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=631897 as a possible cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LXAppearance is the culprit after all. See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=125540

I tried copying the configuration file created by it to .config/gtk-3.0. After restarting gnome-terminal, the menus disappeared completely (or to be precisely everything is nearly zero-sized, and there is text). After commenting the .config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini line-by-line the culprit is gtk-font-name. Anyhow, this proves that gnome-terminal is a GTK3 app which does read the settings.

**Solution**  was to install gnome-themes-standard and edit .config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini to  say "gtk-theme-name=Adwaita" (it is the only theme in the package, but it suits me fine).

Final remark: confusingly in the directory /usr/share/themes many themes have gtk-3.0 subfolder without being GTK3 themes. I hope it is of help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a solution for you if you're trying to avoid too many Gnome dependencies, but I solved it by making sure `gnome-settings-daemon` was starting in my `.xinitrc`: after starting that, all my GTK2/3 applications suddenly paid attention to a whole load of settings they'd previously been ignoring. You can then use `gnome-tweak-tool` to change themes (or possibly `lxappearance` and then log out & in again?).

I don't know where it lives on Ubuntu, but I found it in `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon` on my Arch system (it used to live in the `$PATH` before Gnome 3).

Hope that helps!